# How to add phone numbers from database to <a href="tel:"> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<a href="tel:<?php echo $b2b_mec_num; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn" id="CallBtn">&nbsp;CALL</button></a>
```

I need to add phone numbers from database to the anchor tag above.
How do I do that?

**Edit from Comment:**

```
$sql_m="select * FROM b2b_mec_tbl where b2b_shop_id=$b2b_shop_id"; // tracking table $sql_mec=mysqli_query($con,$sql_m) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_mec=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_mec);
$b2b_mec_num=$row_mec['b2b_mobile_number_1'];
```

Comment: You need to include database information (structure and how you get the data)

Comment: $sql_m="select * FROM b2b_mec_tbl where b2b_shop_id=$b2b_shop_id";  // tracking  table
 $sql_mec=mysqli_query($con,$sql_m) or die(mysqli_error());
 $row_mec=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_mec);
 $b2b_mec_num=$row_mec['b2b_mobile_number_1'];

Comment: Please modify your original question with that information

Answer (score 1):

You were close here is how I would do it.

```
<?php 
$con='DBCONNECT STRING HERE';
$sql_m="select * FROM b2b where b2b_id = '$b2b_id'";
$sql_mec=mysqli_query($con,$sql_m) or die(mysqli_error());

while($row_mec=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_mec)){ 
  $b2b_mec_num=$row_mec['b2b_mobile'];
}
?>

<a href="tel:<? echo $b2b_mec_num; ?>">
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="CallBtn">
    &nbsp;CALL
  </button>
</a>
```